# New Project, Old Nuget

Tags: nuget, visual-studio-2017

Every time I start a new MVC project in Visual Studio, I have to update my Nuget packages. Things are several versions behind. I'm regularly updating my Visual Studio to stay current there, but how do I make sure my packages are up to date in new framework?

If needed, running Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What update of Visual Studio 2017 are you on?
How about modifying the inbuilt templates?

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\Web\CSharp\1033
```

Comment: Huh, would have thought there'd be a option or something in the settings I was missing. This is surprisingly manual.

Comment: Not that I know of. The difference is, the ones that shipped with VS were probably tested and compatibility ensured across them all. When they release updates, the templates can be updated too. What update of VS are you on? They are up to Update 5 for 2017.

Comment: Are you satifsfied with the answer?

Comment: Giving it a day before marking it. I like to give time in case someone else has some other insight. But barring that, I'll mark it this evening.